# dlsym-like functionality for non-dynamically-loaded code?

Tags: c, reflection, debug-symbols, dlsym

I know how to use `dlsym()` to find symbols keyed by a string - when these symbols are exported by a shared library which I've `dlopen()`ed. But - what about other code? Just object code I've linked statically. Is it possible to somehow lookup symbols?

**Notes:**

- If it helps, make any reasonable assumptions about the compilation and linking process (e.g. which compiler, presence of debug info, PIC code etc.)
- I'm interested more in a non-OS-specific solution, but if it matters: Linux.
- Solutions involving pre-registration of functions are not relevant. Or rather, maybe they are, but I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed just use `dlsym()` for that purpose.. You just have to export *all* symbols to the dynamic symbol table. Link the binary with `gcc -rdynamic` for that.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void foo (void) {
    puts("foo");
}

int main (void) {
    void (*foo)(void) = dlsym(NULL, "foo");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc -rdynamic -O2 dl.c -o dl -ldl`

```
$ ./dl
foo
$
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you... it's not gcc-specific, though, right?

Comment: Well, it's more a matter of the linker. gcc just passes `-export-dynamic` to `ld` when `-rdynamic` is specified. Any ELF-linker should support it one way or another. It of course doesn't work, if the binary format doesn't know a symbol table or similar construct.

Comment: Note that if you link a static library, the only symbols from the library accessible via this method will be those exported by the object files actually linked in the executable.